Grooming and dress code standards
What does the law in Tennessee say about an employer's right to implement grooming and dress code standards for employees?
Does it matter if the motive is based on the religious beliefs of the owner?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

With the edit, I withdraw my close vote.
